# Refreshing an observable array to its initial value

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observableArray in my UI that populates a certain modal dialog.
This observableArray also contains a List within it which passes data to a List control in the UI.

Now, say the user makes some changes to the List control BUT decides to click 'Cancel' on the modal window so as to re-open it(he is expecting his changes to be gone)

In my case, the data retains its old value.
I tried saving the initial data of the observableArray into a regular array, so as to refresh the observableArray on the 'Cancel' event, but that didn't work.

Apologies for my vagueness,
Here are a few snippets.
Hopefully, they make sense.

// Lets call the observable array as MyObservableArray//
// This array will later populate 3 texts and ONE listbox(data to this comes from the List)

// Binding and Declarations //

```
this.MyObservableArray = ko.observableArray();   
var unsavedMyObservable = ([]);
```

// This is the function that first populates the observable array on the change // of a dropdown.

```
var getData = this.dropDown.subscribe(function (pid) {    
this.MyObservableArray(data)
```

// Here I try to preserve the data from the observable array into a regular array with the intention of using it later in the event of cancel //

```
unsavedMyObservable = self.MyObservableArray();  

}
```

// Next the user makes some selections on the Listbox but decides to hit Cancel,

```
self.cancelDialog= function () {

self.MyObservableArray(unsavedMyObservable);


};
```

Comment: please give some codes, it's easier to get your idea

Comment: Your question is asking us to imagine the code and at the same time solve the problem, while you have the code right in front of you and you alone know what it looks like. 
You realize you're not making it easy for us to help you? Please show what you're talking about. You can use snippets in your question editor. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: My apologies, I have edited my initial post.
Hopefully it makes more sense this time.
Thanks for taking time for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> unsavedMyObservable = self.MyObservableArray();
> ```

This does not make a copy of the data, because objects (including Arrays) are references: when you assign an array to a variable, the variable refers to the same array contents. Changes to `MyObservableArray` will show up in `unsavedMyObservable`.

Have a look at [Guard Your Model](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html), which introduces the `protectedObservable` extension.

Comment: Thanks Roy !
That was exactly what I was looking for.
Appreciate the help !